# Proving that $A=A(B−I)$ and $B=B(A−I)$ implies $A$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-rank

Let $A, B \in K^{n \times n}$.

I found that $2$ and $0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Then I tried to prove that $rank(2I-A)=rank(A)$ if so the $nul(A) + nul(2I-A) = n$ and that means $A$ is diagonalizable. But I cant prove it. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You don't want ${\rm rank}(2I-A)={\rm rank}(A)$, you want ${\rm null}(2I-A)={\rm rank}(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

The assumptions can be rewritten as $AB=2A$ and $BA=2B.$ Therefore $Bx=0$ iff $Ax=0.$ Hence
$\dim \ker A=\dim \ker B.$ The identity $B(A-2I)=0$ implies that $$\dim \ker B\ge \dim{\rm Im} (A-2I)=n-\dim\ker(A-2I)$$ Hence
$$\dim\ker A+\dim\ker (A-2I)\ge n$$
Therefore the whole space can be decomposed into the direct sum of $\ker A$ and $\ker (A-2I).$

Comment: Why does $Bx=0$ imply $Ax=0$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger $ABx=2Ax.$

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\ker(A-2I)$ then $Ax=2x$ so
$$2x=A(B-I)x=ABx-2x\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=A(\tfrac14Bx)\in{\rm im}(A)\ ,$$
so $\ker(A-2I)\subseteq{\rm im}(A)$.  Conversely, your equations imply $A^2=2A$, so if $x\in{\rm im}(A)$ then
$$(A-2I)x=(A-2I)Av=(A^2-2A)v=0\ .$$
Thus $\ker(A-2I)={\rm im}(A)$.

Comment: why ker(A−2I)=im(A) here (A2−2A)v=0  you wrote 0v=0. and even if its true it means that nul(A-2I)=p(A) which dont prove that A is diagonalizable/
 .

Comment: How can $0v$ be anything else except $0$????  Sorry, I don't think I understood your comment.